# How do I use the params/get the controller for a hook in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I have a post-controller hook:

```
$hook['post_controller'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'PostControllerHook',
    'function' => 'post_controller',
    'filename' => 'PostControllerHook.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => array('controller')
);
```

The [hooks documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) says that I can specify paramaters for my hook. How do I specify these parameters? Also, I need to have access to my controller object, which is why I'm trying to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the parameters correctly.

Are you expecting to have access to the controller that just ran, prior to the **post_controller** hook? That won't work quite the way you expect. Code Igniter will try to instantiate a class if you pass it one for the hook, so you can't pass the controller instance directly.

Imagine first you have a controller

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller
{
    public function doHookStuff()
    {
        echo "I'm running in a hook I hope!";
    }
}
```

What you can do is call the `get_instance` helper function from your hook.

```
class PostControllerHook
{
  function post_controller($params)
  {
     // $params[0] = 'controller' (given the params in the question)

     // $controller is now your controller instance,
     // the same instance that just handled the request
     $controller =& get_instance();

     $controller->doHookStuff();
  }
}
```

If you want more info, all the answers are sitting in *system/core/CodeIgniter.php* and *system/core/Hooks.php*. A little complicated, but not too bad.

Comment: Wait, I don't even know how I'm passing parameters. How is $controller set? Basically, I need to save/return a variable with my controller, and then wrap it in post_controller.

Comment: `$CI` is the controller in the example I've shown. You could put `$controller =& get_instance();` if you prefer though. I made some changes to my answer that should clear it up; see what you think.

Comment: So if I changed `params` to `array('apple', 'banana', 'grape')`, hen those are static strings passed into the hook, and not variable names? I don't see the point of this params key.

Comment: The array gets passed directly into the function you specify for the hook... If you pass `array('apple', 'banana', 'grape')`, then that exact array is supplied to the hook function as I showed in the comment in post_controller in the sample hook). I guess I don't understand the confusion. Maybe you don't need parameters in your case?

Comment: I guess the thing to take home here is that hook parameters are statically defined as part of the hook configuration. They aren't dynamic.

Comment: I just tested this and it works! Thank you. I still don't see the difference between defining params versus hard-coding the values in the hook itself, but to each his own I suppose.

Comment: Is there a way I can access data in `post_controller` method which I will define in `doHookStuff ` method?

Comment: @DeepakBiswal Yes, just return the data you want from the `doHookStuff` method. `$dataFromDoHookStuff = $controller->doHookStuff()`.